# In Wordpress add a menu link to download a file

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Does anyone know of a Wordpress plugin that would allow users to create a new menu link to download a file from the media manager without using 'Custom Links' type? I'm aware that I can upload the file, copy the URL then paste that into the Custom Link when creating a new menu link, but my client will be administering the site and is having trouble figuring out how the whole copy/paste process.

It seems like there should be an option for 'Media' when creating a new menu link which would open up the media manager to select the URL directly, or at least a plugin to add this functionality. I've searched for the last hour with no luck so thought I might be missing something.